# Prove that set of all points on a sphere is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Let $S=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=4\}$ be the set of points on a sphere. Prove $S$ is uncountable.

**Attempt**: Basically, each coordinate is between $0$ and $2$, i.e. $0\le x \le 2, 0\le y \le 2, 0\le z \le2$. So if I prove that for some $a$ set $A=\{a \in \mathbb{R}: 0 \le a \le 2\}$ is uncountable, then $A\times A\times A$ is also uncountable. Then, I would try to find a one to one function between $A\times A\times A$ and $S$, i.e. $f: A\times A\times A \rightarrow S$ which will prove that $S$ is uncountable.

The difficulties I have are: how do I prove that $A$ is uncountable? Would fucntion $f(a,a,a)=(x,y,z)$ work? Is it the right approach? Thank you.

Comment: The [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) maps the sphere minus one point bijectively to the plane.

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to fix e.g. $z=0$ and take $y=\sqrt {4-x^2}$ and see what set of values $x$ can take on...

Comment: Not to ruffle any feathers, but the question posed was not asking for a solution, but a critique of his exhibited approach. Kudos @lhf, who presented an excellent hint along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\{ (x,y), x^2 + y^2 = 4 \} = S^1 \subset S^2 = S$$
if you set $z=0$ in an embedding. Then find $S^1 \sim [0, 2\pi)$ via $\phi \mapsto 4(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ which is uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Show that $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is injective on $(0,2)$, and conclude that $x\mapsto(x,\sqrt{4-x^2},0)$ is an injection from $[0,2]$ into $A$.

Comment: Isn't injectivity of $x\mapsto x$ sufficient to prove that $x\mapsto(x,\sqrt{4-x^2},0)$ is injective?

Comment: It's late and I'm somewhat busy with other issues. You might be right.

Comment: @DejanGovc On behalf of Asaf: Yes, it is, since the image is therefor already injectively specified by the first component.

Comment: @AsafKaragila For every x?

Comment: @Koba: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you start your answer "For every Show..." for every what?

Comment: @Koba: LOL. I didn't even notice that. As I said, it's late and I'm somewhat preoccupied with other problems. :-)